# Why is registry-1.docker.io called?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm trying to deploy an application from an image in a docker on a production server, but when I run the command to start the container:

docker-compose up -d

I get is this error:
Error response from daemon: Get "https://.../cpauth?scheme=https&4Tmthd=0&host=registry-1.docker.io&port=443&uri=L3YyLw==&"": tls: server chose an unconfigured cipher suite

To build the image on our server I used the following command:
docker build -t local/m2v-debug:master_NR

My question is:
Why is the address registry-1.docker.io called? If I understand correctly it stands for DNS name for Docker Hub. I thought there is no need to pull something from an external registry when starting container from an already prepared image?

If any more information is needed just let mne know.

Sorry if this is a stupid question but I'm pretty new to all this. Thanks!

I and 2 of my colleagues tried to create the containers on our own Debian VMs with no problem.

So the docker images | grep m2m-debug:master_NR didn't return anything. However docker images returns this:

```
REPOSITORY               TAG         IMAGE ID       CREATED         SIZE
local/m2v-debug          master_NR   a59a0f872ce8   30 hours ago    2.94GB
```

Here is the YML file:

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  m2v:
    image: local/m2v-debug:master_NR
    container_name: m2v_1.0.4_debug
    restart: always
    dns_search: .
    user: root
    ports:
      - 93:80
      - 8893:443
      - 3503:3490
    volumes:
      - /opt/docker/m2v_1.0.4_debug/data:/data
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "curl", "-f", "http://127.0.0.1/epoch"]
      interval: 1m30s
      timeout: 11s
      retries: 5
      start_period: 5s
    networks:
      - proxynet
    logging:
      driver: "json-file"
      options:
        max-size: "100M"
        max-file: "3"
networks:
  proxynet:
    external: false
```

Comment: Can you share your `docker-compose.yml`? Also, what is the output of `docker images | grep m2v-debug:master_NR`?

Comment: One possible hint here is that images that don't explicitly name a registry are assumed to be on `docker.io`; so for example `ubuntu` is internally expanded to `docker.io/library/ubuntu:latest`.  If the image doesn't actually exist locally (or the `docker build -t` name doesn't match the Compose `image:` name) you could see something like this.

Comment: @Tschösi I added the info in my question. Doest it help?

Comment: @Richard Thanks!
Can you try to add `pull_policy: never` to your m2v service and see what happens?

Comment: @Tschösi Sorry for my late reply. Your solution worked. Instead of an error message about pulling the image from the hub, we got an error saying that the problem was really in the name of the image, a stupid typo. So thanks a lot. :)